# Biometric sdk development

Tags: biometrics

I have to develop an sdk for biometric applications, but don't know how to start development. Either I need to write my own algorithm or use written by other and are free. If I use others algorithm then it is difficult to say about the quality and results.
Is there any standard source available that can help me in term of quality.
I don't wanna use any available sdk
Anybody who can help me in this regard will be a plus for me.

Thanks

Khizar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming for biometric devices depends largely on the device you use. Chances are you've received software with your device that has its own evaluation algorithim which then outputs a value, usually a hash, that your program can then handle.

If you're looking for a generic option, Google has several. One option being [m2sys](http://www.m2sys.com/hybrid-biometric-platform.htm).

Comment: Shane If I use Fujitsu Palm vein reader then what? Can u suggest any architecture that i can follow?

Comment: Have you looked into this: http://www.frontech.fujitsu.com/en/services/palmsecure/sdk/ ?

Comment: Yeah, I have seen that but I wanna develop my own sdk for Palm Vein reader and for 3 other devices. hope you got my point.